# R: number of days to month end using lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate

I am trying to calculate the number of days remaining in the current month using the lubridate package. I have been able to successfully accomplish this using the code below; however, this seems to be very verbose and difficult to read.

```
as.duration(interval(start = ymd(Sys.Date()), end =  ceiling_date(Sys.Date(), unit = "month"))) / ddays(1)
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Doesn't just `ceiling_date(Sys.Date(), "months") - Sys.Date() - 1` provide what you're asking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In lubridate you can do:

```
days_in_month(now()) - mday(now())
```

Although that gives you a named vector, so it's better to do

```
as.numeric(days_in_month(now()) - mday(now()))
#> [1] 27
```

Thanks to @H1 for pointing out we can use `now()` instead of `month(now())`

Answer (score 0):

Based on @WaltS' suggestion, we can use `ceiling_date` with "month" as unit to get start date of next month, subtract 1 day from it to get end date of current month and then subtract today's date to get remaining days in the month.

```
as.integer(ceiling_date(today(), "months") - today() - 1)
```